# Logging help needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to automate a personal telescope and I have managed to code a camera module, a test driver to run everything and I am working on a logger module for future module debugging. I am having a very hard and frustrating time trying to get errors from the camera module to send to the logger module and then print to my desktop. Pls help.

I have tried and tried again to get any form of log from the cAmera.py folder to print onto the log sheet. There is a problem with filling the log function's 'self' requirement inside of the camera modules. So I made a work around and made logger go before self in camera and I was able to print a test case but not the cases in the if statement.

logger.py

```py
import logging
from main.common import cAmera
from main.common.cAmera import *

class main:

    # creates filehandlers
    fh = logging.FileHandler('C:\\Users\\Nicholas Pepin\\Desktop\\CameraErrorLog.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    # Creates console logger for higher level logging
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    # Creates Formatters
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    # adds handlers to the logger
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.info('Camera process has started : ' + __name__)
    cAmera.Camera.log(logging, logger)  # need to fulfil self
    # Theoretically, it works. but in 'cAmera.Camera.log()' it says that self needs to be fulfilled
    # and I have no idea how to do that. If someone could help guide me to a paper or video that would
    # explain it, that would be very helpful.
```

cAmera.py

```py
import os
import time
import win32com.client
import logging
class Camera:
    def __init__(self, logger, output_directory):
        # __all__ = ['__init__', 'Camera']  # for some reason, opens up the class and __init__ file?
        # output_directory starts from user path
        self.logger = logger
        logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.output_directory = output_directory
        self.camera = win32com.client.Dispatch("MaxIm.CCDCamera")  # Sets the camera connection path to the CCDCamera
        try:
            self.camera.LinkEnabled = True
            logger.info("Camera is connected : "+__name__)
        except:
            logger.critical("Camera is not connected : "+__name__)
        self.camera.DisableAutoShutdown = True  # All of these settings are just basic camera setup settings.
        self.camera.AutoDownload = True

    def expose(self, exposure_time, filter, type="light"):
        if type == "light":
            type = 1
        elif type == "dark":
            type = 0
        else:
            print("ERROR: Invalid exposure type.")
            return
        self.camera.SetFullFrame()
        self.camera.Expose(exposure_time, type, filter)
        time.sleep(exposure_time)
        while self.camera.ImageReady == False:
            time.sleep(1)
            if self.camera.ImageReady:
                # self.camera.StartDownload
                path = os.path.expanduser('~')
                self.camera.SaveImage(os.path.join(path, 'Desktop', "test_pictures.fit"))

    def log(logger, self):
        logger.info("Camera test " + __name__)
        if self.camera.LinkEnabled:
            logger.info("Camera is connected : "+__name__)
        elif not self.camera.LinkEnabled:
            logger.critical("Camera cannot connect : "+__name__)

    def set_gain(self):
        pass

    def set_binning(self):
        pass
```

test_driver.py

```py
from main.common.cAmera import *
from main.common.logger import *

#activates the camera function
camera_object = Camera("camera_work")
camera_object.expose(10, 1, type="dark")

#activates the logger function
main('camera_work')
```

I hope to see just an in-depth logger printout on my computer detailing the different ways the code screwed up. Also, if anyone can critique my code and provide help on making me a better programmer, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you get error message ?always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you set `self.logger = logger` but `logger` has no value. And later you assign `logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)` which makes no sense. You could set `logger = ...` before `self.logger = logger` or use `Camera("camera_work", logging.getLogger(__name__))`.

Comment: all methods should use `self.` as first argument - `log(self, other-aruments)` in `Camera`. And `cAmera.Camera.log(logging, logger)` make no sense because you run it without creating instance of `Camera` so there is no `self.camera` which is created in `__init__`. You should create `cam = cAmera.Camera()` and later use `cam.log(logger)` (with `def log(self, logger))`)

Answer (score 0):

You have `logger` in class init as parameter but you don't use it.

```
class Camera:
    def __init__(self, logger, output_directory):
        self.logger = logger
        logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Remove `logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)`

```
class Camera:
    def __init__(self, logger, output_directory):
        self.logger = logger
```

and run as

```
Camera(logger, "/output/directory")
```

or assing this logger as default value in class

```
class Camera:
    def __init__(self, output_directory, logger=None):
        if logger:
            self.logger = logger
        else:
            self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and use with existing logger

```
 logger = ...
 Camera("directory/output", logger)
```

or with logger created inside class

```
 Camera("directory/output")
```

---

Now you should use `self.logger` in all methods in Camera

```
def __init__(self, logger, output_directory):
        if logger:
            self.logger = logger
        else:
            self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        self.output_directory = output_directory
        self.camera = win32com.client.Dispatch("MaxIm.CCDCamera")

        try:
            self.camera.LinkEnabled = True
            self.logger.info("Camera is connected : {}".format(__name__))
        except Exception as ex:
            sel.logger.critical("Camera is not connected : {} ({})".format(__name__, ex))
        self.camera.DisableAutoShutdown = True
        self.camera.AutoDownload = True
```

Ther same in method `log

```
def log(self):
    self.logger.info("Camera test : {}".format(__name__))

    if self.camera.LinkEnabled:
        self.logger.info("Camera is connected : {}".format(__name__))
    elif not self.camera.LinkEnabled:
        self.logger.critical("Camera cannot connect : {}".format(__name__))
```

To use `Camera` you have to create instance

```
cam = cAmera.Camera("directory/output", logger)
cam.log()
```

---

If you create instance before `main` (which probably should be `def` instead of `class`) then put it as arguments

```
camera_object = Camera("directory/output")
camera_object.expose(10, 1, type="dark")

main('camera_work', camera_object)


def main(text, camera):

    cam = camera
    cam.log()
```

or better do it after you create logger

```
main('camera_work')


def main(text):

    logger = ...

    camera_object = Camera("directory/output", logger)
    camera_object.expose(10, 1, type="dark")

    camera_object.log()
```